# Only allow Specific Domain within a Text Input Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, url

Ok so I've got a text input box which is for people to link there Tripadvisor page to a profile. I want it so when they paste the URL in it gets checked for the correct URL, so if: http://www.tipadvisor.com/ or if http://tripadvisor.com/ then allow link but if something like: http://www.differentdomain.com is inputed it will reject it.

Is there anything in JavaScript or jQuery that could do this?

All advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* author Vicky Gonsalves*/  
function tValid(url) {  
var p = /^(?:http?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)? (?:tripadvisor.com\/)?$/;   
return (url.match(p)) ? RegExp.$1 : false;   
}
```

this function will match if the provided string is a valid tripadvisor.com or not and will return true or false accordingly

example usage:

```
<input type='text' id='tripurl' />  
<button type='button' onclick='validateUrl()'>validate</button>  
<script>  
var url=document.getElementById('tripurl').value;  
if(tValid){  
// url is valid  
}else{  
//url is invalid  
}  
</script>
```